# Sparse checkout but exclude or ignore files in root?

Tags: git, sparse-checkout, git-sparse-checkout

The docs for `git sparse-checkout` state,

> **By default, when running git sparse-checkout init, the root directory is added as a parent pattern.** At this point, the sparse-checkout file contains the following patterns:
>
> ```
> /*
> !/*/
> ```

However, I do not want to include the root in `sparse-checkout` I want something like,

```
/directory_i_want
!/*
!/*/
```

But that doesn't work, returning instead

> warning: unrecognized pattern: `/*`
>
> warning: disabling cone pattern matching

Such that the sparse-checkout only pulls the one directory at the top, and **not ever file in the repository's root**. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

You are seeing that because you have enabled `sparseCheckoutCone`. From the reference:

> The accepted patterns in the cone pattern set are:
>
> 1. Recursive: All paths inside a directory are included.
> 2. Parent: All files immediately inside a directory are included.
>
> In addition to the above two patterns, **we also expect that all files
> in the root directory are included**.

However it is not automatically enabled, so I wonder why you have it set. Anyway, you clearly cannot use it since you are excluding pretty everything except for `directory_i_want`. First of all, disable that option:

```
git config core.sparseCheckoutCone 'false'
```

Next, restore the initial repo:

```
git sparse-checkout disable
```

And in the end, choose the pattern you need with

```
git sparse-checkout set directory_i_want/
```

If you now look at the file `$GIT_DIR/info/sparse-checkout`, you will see a very simple pattern (`directory_i_want/`) and that is enough. Consider that with the `sparse-checkout` you tried, the order is important: you cannot put `directory_i_want` at the start and then negate it with `!/*/`. It would result in an error saying something like:

> error: Sparse checkout leaves no entry on working directory